# Lipschitz map on Positive Definite cone of n-by-n matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-writing, lipschitz-functions, positive-definite

A function matrix $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is a convex Lipschitz continuous matrix function with Lipschitz constant $\mathrm L$ with respect to a fixed given norm $\|\cdot\|$, i.e., $|f(A)-f(B)| \leq \mathrm L \cdot \|A-B\|$, $\forall A,~B \in X$.

Considering $X$ as Positive Definite cone of $n$-by-$n$ matrices, are the following maps Lipschitz continuous with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$? (I was able to prove the convexity.)

1. $\mathrm{Trace}$ of inverse: $\mathrm{Trace}((\cdot)^{-1})$?
2. Inverse of the minimum eigenvalue: $1/\lambda_{\min}(\cdot)$?

If yes, what would be the Lipschitz constants for them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the trace is linear, you'd need to show that inverting is Lipschitz, however this is not so as the matrices of $1\times 1$ already show. Same for the second case.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamM. for your answer. To confirm we are in the same page, consider $f(x) = 1/x$ as the $1 \times 1$ case, then for all $a,b \in (c,\infty)$, we have $|f(a)-f(b)| = \frac{|a-b|}{|ab|} \leq \frac{1}{c^2}|a-b|$. However, since $a$ and $b$ have to be PD, so $c = 0$ and Lipschitz does not hold, right?

Comment: That $f$ is not Lipschitz means that there exists sequences $a_n, b_n$ such that $|f(a_n)-f(b_n)|/|a_n-b_n|\to \infty.$ Take $a_n = 1$ and $b_n=1/n.$